# Posting the message to Telegram gets failed after some attempt

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, xmlhttprequest

I created the program using python to post message in the group.
I tested and it worked fine. I just posted only 5 messages.
From yesterday i am getting the below error.
I have posted the code and error message which i am getting.
I am using pycharm ide.

code:-

```
import requests
import telegram

def TelegramSendViaAPI():
    # Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the actual token you obtained from the BotFather
    bot_token = '261600102:rrrdddfffxxxx'
    bot = telegram.Bot(token='261600102:AdfsdfsfsdfsdfewjA')
    # Replace 'CHAT_ID' with the actual chat ID where you want to send the message
    chat_id = '@mypythontesting'

    # Replace 'Your message here' with the actual message you want to send
    message_text = 'Congratulations :) Om Vijayalakshmi Namaha'

    api_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage'


    params = {
    'chat_id': chat_id,
    'text': message_text,
    }

    response = requests.post(api_url, json=params)

    # Print the response from the Telegram server
    print(response.json())

TelegramSendViaAPI()
```

Error :-

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\selenium_learning\messageposting.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 210, in _new_conn
    raise NameResolutionError(self.host, self, e) from e
urllib3.exceptions.NameResolutionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001275283A790>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot261600102:AAsdfsasfdasfdasduRljA/sendMessage (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001275283A790>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\selenium_learning\messageposting.py", line 27, in <module>
    TelegramSendViaAPI()
  File "E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\selenium_learning\messageposting.py", line 22, in TelegramSendViaAPI
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot261600102:AAGxsfsfdsfsfsddfs6VqD67uRljA/sendMessage (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001275283A790>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me to solve.
i need to use this for posting the alerts to my telegram channel.